# How to check if an array is not empty and some specific values of it are numeric?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two declared arrays with some parameters. First of all I need to check if the array is not empty and then if specific parameters of the first array are numeric.

Now I have two arrays. One of them has all parameters and the second has only the parameters thas have to be numeric (that are included in the first array too)

I want to do both checks in a method because I have them in two differents ones.

This is what I have

```
/** Array con parametros no obligatorios   Array con los parametros obligatorios. */
private static final String[] PARAMETROS_OBLIGATORIOS = new String[] {
    "idFichero","nombreFichero","qnuOrdest","idHsc","timCamestad","codGrupoest","qnuOrdestRcvd"
};

/** Array con los parametros que deben ser numericos. */
private static final String[] PARAMETROS_NUMERICOS = new String[] {
    "idFichero","idHsc","qnuOrdest","qnuOrdestRcvd"
};

private void validarObligatorios(final JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
    for (String nombre : PARAMETROS_OBLIGATORIOS) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(parameters.getString(nombre))) {
            String error ="El parametro " + nombre + " es obligatorio"; 
            LOGGER.error(error);
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException(error);
        }

    }
}



private void validarNumericos(final JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
    for (String nombre : PARAMETROS_NUMERICOS) {
        if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(parameters.getString(nombre))) {
            String error = "El parametro " + nombre + " debe ser numerico"; 
            LOGGER.error(error);
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException(error);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to do both steps in a unique method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A small advice: it`s better to name your variables in english.

Comment: Make a new method and call the other two in it. Or, combine them into one method.

Comment: isBlank doesn't automatically mean there is no String. "" is a blank, but it's also a String.

Comment: Thanks to all. I combined them in a method but I want to do both validations in only one. The reason the variables are not named in english is because they are database columns named like that.

Answer (score 0):

Would replacing your 2 methods `validarObligatorios` and `validarNumericas` by the following single function answer your question??

```
private void validarObligatoriosYNumericos(final JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
    for (String nombre : PARAMETROS_OBLIGATORIOS) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(parameters.getString(nombre))) {
            String error ="El parametro " + nombre + " es obligatorio"; 
            LOGGER.error(error);
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException(error);
        }

    }

    for (String nombre : PARAMETROS_NUMERICOS) {
        if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(parameters.getString(nombre))) {
            String error = "El parametro " + nombre + " debe ser numerico"; 
            LOGGER.error(error);
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException(error);
        }
    }
}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the numeric columns array into a list and use `contains` to see if a value should be checked. This solution assumes that the numeric column array is a sub-set of the mandatory column array but it looks like that is a safe assumption.

```
private void validarObligatorios(final JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
    List<String> numericColumns = Arrays.asList(PARAMETROS_NUMERICOS );
    String error = null;
    for (String nombre : PARAMETROS_OBLIGATORIOS) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(parameters.getString(nombre))) {
            error ="El parametro " + nombre + " es obligatorio"; 
        } else if (numericColumns.contains(nombre) {
            if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(parameters.getString(nombre))) {
               error = "El parametro " + nombre + " debe ser numerico";                     
            }
        }
        if (error != null)  {
            LOGGER.error(error);
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException(error);                
        }
    }
}
```